# SQL - ORDER BY, GROUP BY with id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `messages` with columns `Id, SenderAccountId, ReceiverAccountId, Message, DateTime`.

When I try to only select the newest messages for each `SenderAccountId` with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
GROUP BY SenderAccountId
ORDER BY DateTime ASC
```

I get this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'Chats.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

But when I change the SELECT to

```
SELECT SenderAccountId, ReceiverAccountId, Message, DateTime
```

My error just moves to the next column (so: `SenderAccountId`)

Is there a way to get the right result with another query?

Comment: There is no aggregation function (sum, max, etc.) in your query for the "group by".

Comment: I have to get all the columns for the rest of the program, so aggreation functions are not an option unfortunatly

Comment: When using `GROUP BY` in SQL Server, the rule is very simple: **every** column in your `SELECT` list of columns (and you should really use **explicit lists of columns** - not just `*` !) **must be** either in an aggregate (SUM, COUNT, AVG, MIN, MAX), **or then** it **must be** included in the `GROUP BY` statement. If you don't have any aggregates at all, a `GROUP BY` really doesn't make any sense at all ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would seem to be looking for something like:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m
WHERE m.DateTime = (SELECT MAX(m2.DateTime) FROM messages m2 WHERE m2.SenderAccountId = m.SenderAccountId);
```

Aggregation is not really the right approach for writing this query.  You want to think "filtering" instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use group by without aggreation function (as max(), count(), min())

if yoy want distinct result you should use disticnt clause and for this avoid * (ALL COLUMN )

```
SELECT distinct col1, col2..., coln
FROM messages
ORDER BY DateTime ASC'
```

Comment: Unfortunatly distinct is not possible because of the datetime and the id. And I have to get all the columns for the rest of the program, so aggreation functions are not an option unfortunatly

Comment: You must remeber that the use of group by without aggreation function is not allowed  in most database and in the most recent version of mysql  (starting from mysql 5.7) so if you want distinct result you must use distinct clause and explicti column name in select

Answer (score 0):

MySQL extends the standard SQL use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause.

[check this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query :

```
SELECT m1.* FROM messages m1
inner join 
(SELECT SenderAccountId, MAX(DateTime) FROM messages group by SenderAccountId) as m2
on m1.SenderAccountId = m2.SenderAccountId;
```